# spring jpa many to many remove only the association

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, many-to-many

I did some digging into how to delete only a many to many association without deleting either entities, and all that I have found were tutorials or samples on how to delete one of the entities without cascading deletion to the other entity or to the whole table (when using CascadeType.ALL).

So: I have two tables and a many to many table holding the relationship between them.

```
authors( int author_id, varchar author_name )
books( int book_id, varchar book_name )
author_x_book( int author_id, int book_id )
```

An author can have many books, a book can have many authors. I do not enter into the details about primary keys and foreign keys and why I chose that design etc.

JPA Entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "authors")
@Data
public class Author implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "author_id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "author_name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.DETACH})
    @JoinTable(name = "author_x_book",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "author_id", referencedColumnName = "author_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "book_id", referencedColumnName = "book_id"))
    private List<Book> books;
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "books")
@Data
public class Book implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "book_id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "book_name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "books", fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
        cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.DETACH})
    private List<Author> authors;
}
```

I am trying to delete only the entry in the author_x_book - that is, to remove the association between a specific book and a specific author. I do not intend to delete neither the author nor the book, since the book may have other authors and the author may have some other books.

I tried to remove the author from Book.authors and the book from Author.books then persist both the book and the author.

```
@Transactional
public void deleteAssociation(String authorName, String bookName)
{
    Author author = authorRepository.findFirstByName(authorName);
    Book book = bookRepository.findFirstByName(bookName);
    deleteAssociation(author, book);
}

private void deleteAssociation(Author author, Book book) {
    book.getAuthors().remove(author);
    author.getBooks().remove(book);
    authorRepository.save(author);
    bookRepository.save(book);
}
```

Not working. It tries to delete all author's association to all his books. Then it tries to add that association back. Sql logs:

```
delete 
from
    "public"."author_x_book" 
where
    "author_id"=?

insert 
into
    "public"."author_x_book" ("author_id", "book_id") 
values
    (?, ?)
```

Then I created an AuthorXBook entity with and @EmbeddedId and an AuthorXBookRepository.

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "author_x_book")
public class AuthorXBook implements Serializable {
    @EmbeddedId
    private AuthorXBookId id;

    @Data
    @Embeddable
    public static class AuthorXBookId implements Serializable {
        @Column(name = "author_id", nullable = false)
        private final long authorId;
        @Column(name = "book_id", nullable = false)
        private final long bookId;
    }
}

@Repository
public interface AuthorXBookRepository extends CrudRepository<AuthorXBook, AuthorXBook.AuthorXBookId> {
}
```

When calling AuthorXBookRepository.delete(authorXBook):

```
private void deleteAssociation(Author author, Book book) {
    authorXBookRepository.delete(new AuthorXBook.AuthorXBookId(author.getId(), book.getId()));
    book.getAuthors().remove(author);
    author.getBooks().remove(book);
    authorRepository.save(author);
    bookRepository.save(book);
}
```

It does a select, not a delete, than it goes on by deleting all books from the author and adding back the association:

```
select
    authorxboo0_."author_id" as author_1_20_0_,
    authorxboo0_."book_id" as book_2_20_0_ 
from
    "public"."author_x_book" authorxboo0_ 
where
    authorxboo0_."author_id"=? 
    and authorxboo0_."book_id"=?

delete 
from
    "public"."author_x_book" 
where
    "author_id"=?

insert 
into
    "public"."author_x_book" ("author_id", "book_id") 
values
    (?, ?)
```

I ended up creating a @Modifying @Query to delete the association:

```
@Repository
public interface AuthorXBookRepository extends CrudRepository<AuthorXBook, AuthorXBook.AuthorXBookId> {
    @Modifying
    @Query("delete from #{#entityName} x where x.authorId=:aid and x.bookId=:bid")
    void delete(@Param("aid") long authorId, @Param("bid") long bookId);
}

private void deleteAssociation(Author author, Book book) {
    authorXBookRepository.delete(author.getId(), book.getId());
    book.getAuthors().remove(author);
    author.getBooks().remove(book);
    authorRepository.save(author);
    bookRepository.save(book);
}
```

and it worked. It deletes only the association. And does not try to add it back, I guess because @Modifiable clears the EntityManager.

So, two questions:

1. Why my first and second attempt did not work?
2. What is the correct way to delete only the many to many association, without deleting either entities?

Thank you

Comment: You pass those entites as argument of a method that is marked transactional, but you treat them as persistent entities...
Point is: is that where the transaction start or there's more? are perhaps those argument actually detached or transient entities?

Comment: In fact, there is a caller method that is @Transactional, that loads those two entities then calls deleteAssociation().

Answer (score 0):

use Set instead of List on Owner Side to avoid "delete all then insert leftover again" issue:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "authors")
@Data
public class Author implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "author_id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "author_name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.DETACH})
    private Set<Book> books;  // use Set instead of List on Owner Side
}
```

when remove only relation, saving Owner "Author" is enough after remove the reference from each other,

```java
@Transactional
public void deleteAssociation(String authorName, String bookName)
{
    Author author = authorRepository.findFirstByName(authorName);
    Book book = bookRepository.findFirstByName(bookName);
    deleteAssociation(author, book);
}

private void deleteAssociation(Author author, Book book) {
    book.getAuthors().remove(author);
    author.getBooks().remove(book);
    authorRepository.save(author);  // saving Owner is enought
    // bookRepository.save(book);
}
```

Entity Author and Book need to Override these 2 functions, respectively

```java
@Override 
public boolean equals(Object o) {
   // compare by their Id
}
@Override 
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hashCode(getClass());
}
```